# How can RoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource Property be used to identify the specific UIElement that originated the event

Tags: wpf, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to use the OriginalSource property to determine the specific UIElement that generated a PointerReleased event. According to the documentation RoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource returns the object that originated the event but I don't know how to use that to identify the UIElement. I can use OrginalSource.ToString() to identify the type of UIElement but not a specific instance. My approach may be entirely wrong, if so, that would be worth knowing too. Thanks.

Comment: If you have specific instance why not just compare them using `==` OR using `.Equals` method?

Comment: That works, thanks. I guess I was looking for the object to be able to   identify itself, rather than having to compare it to a set of potential candidates, but I'm not sure it makes much difference. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set of potential candidates to cross check against, you can simply do the equality check between original source and each potential candidate using `==` or using `.Equals()` method of Object.

Secondly, in case you want original source to tell it's identity, what you can do is set `x:Name` on control instance in XAML and then in code you can access `Name` property to validate it's identity.

XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock"/>
```

Code:

```
string sender = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).Name;
```