# To Expand/Collapse Expander on click of text and icon of Expander in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, expander

Is it possible to expand/collapse "Expander" only when icon or the text of "Header" is clicked. This should not expand/collapse when any portion of complete "Expander Header" is clicked.

Please suggest.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937434/how-can-routedeventargs-originalsource-property-be-used-to-identify-the-specific), you can set IsExpanded based on Type (or Name) of the OriginalSource of RoutedEventArgs.

Comment: So, i need to capture the **onclick/mousedown event** on textblock and the icon image and therefore, set the **"IsExpanded"** property for the expander to expand/collapse?

Comment: Correct, but the way this is done with [RoutedEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx) is somewhat special. You can add a handler on the Expander, because the [events bubble up](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464926/To-bubble-or-tunnel-basic-WPF-events).

Comment: It's not a good idea putting code in comments like this. Click on _edit_ under your question, and put it in the correct format.

Comment: Thanks. I'll reformat the same.

Comment: I tried with *PreviewMouseDown Event* on Expander and it worked for me.
Thanks for your help.